Current source in push pull output of pcf8574
I'm using a PCF8574 I/O expander in my design. I noticed that it has a limited current sourcing capability of about 300 µA. I wondered, why is that? The datasheet has the following schematic of each p-port:

Source: Datasheet "PCF8574 Remote 8-Bit I/O Expander for I2C Bus", https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcf8574.pdf, page 11
What is the purpose of the 100 µA current source in the output stage and why is the sourcing output current so low?

This is similar to the MCS-51 (the original 8051) I/O port structure, which lacks the various programmable output modes that almost all modern microcontrollers are capable of. It is known as quasi-bidirectional output, allowing it to send and receive signals without needing to configure the pin as OUTPUT or INPUT up-front. This mode is also commonly referred to as the standard 8051 output mode, as modern 8051 microcontrollers (such as STC15Fxxx and MG82FG5Bxx) allow programmable to different I/O modes.

The quasi-bidirectional mode is somewhat similar to the open-drain (open-collector) output mode with a weak pull-up. However, it has an additional one-shot strong pull-up accelerator to quickly bring the signal up to a HIGH state on 0-to-1 transition.

Unlike open-drain with a weak pull-up, where the signal shape has a sharp 1-to-0 transition but a rounded 0-to-1 transition, the quasi-bidirectional mode delivers sharp transitions for both. This feature is especially useful for signaling protocols like UART/USART and SPI, where the receiver has high input impedance, while keeping the simplicity of not having to program the pin mode (i.e, you can use it as SPI output pin at one point of time and then decide to use it as input pin without needing any pin mode setting [you need to set the pin HIGH, though]).
After the one-shot, the signal is maintained high by the weak pull-up. However, due to this weak pull-up, it is not suitable to drive any load like an LED in a current sourcing manner. The LED can be driven in a current sinking manner (because it has a strong current-sinking NMOS, Q3). If a heavy load needs to be driven in a current sourcing manner, then a digital buffer, transistor buffer, or any circuit buffer is needed (see here).

Wow, very good explanation. Thank you very much :)

Why? It was designed to have "quasi-bidirectional IO". It is not designed to have push-pull output or configurable input/outputs like other chips.
The function of the 100uA pull-up is to keep the pin weakly pulled high like a pull-up resistor, so that it can either be a weak high output when the chip itself does not pull the pin low, or be an input with a pull-up.
The chip has only one read/write register so you can either set pins to low or let them float or read the current status.

Thank you for your answer. Now it is much clearer. Is there a reason for not just using a high value resistor as a pull up?

@Robert Having an actual true resistor is more difficult and expensive to manufacture on silicon and it takes more die area. Internal pull-ups on chips are rarely true resistances, but they are sometimes used.
